# Do outer measures satisfy all the properties of a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I know the definition of a measure and an outer measure; however, does an outer measure by default also fulfill the properties of a measure?

Comment: You might want to read the the definition again, specially subadditivity

Comment: @azarel For a measure, it says it is strictly equal, while the subadditivity allows it to be less than or equal to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not follow automatically, take $X=\{1,2\}$ and define $\mu$ on the power-set by

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu(\emptyset)=0,\\
\mu(\{1\})=1,\\
\mu(\{2\})=1,\\
\mu(X)=1. 
\end{eqnarray*}

I leave to you the verification that this is an outer measure, but not a measure.